# Can't select from database without specifying schema name

Tags: postgresql

I am new to databases and I was trying to set up PostreSQL and trying to query
tables in pgAdmin 4, but I always have to specify schema name as such:

```
SELECT * FROM infection_database.country
```

The database name is the same as the schema name. This is probably not good but I didn't know better.

I tried looking up some solutions and found and tried this, but it didn't fix the issue:

```
ALTER DATABASE infection_database SET search_path="infection_database";
```

Tried both with and without quotation marks if it matters. Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Your given solution works, but it takes effect in new sessions, not in the existing one.

Comment: Well, that's silly. Thank you

Comment: You can use *Alter Session ...* which doesn't need a session restart, but it doesn't last beyond session close either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given solution works, but you need to restart the session for the changes to take effect.

Credit to @jjanes